# Error: Unable to resolve module @firebase/app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use firebase database in react-native Project but, i have a problem can you help me about it ?

[image]

I deleted all node module and package.json and reinstall with yarn but not solved

Comment: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage prefer this link

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.